# How can I speed up android emulator?

Tags: android

Android emulators are very slow.
In my opinion the window do not share memory for emulators.
So please share the way to speed up emulators?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to make android emulator faster beacouse it is also emulating arm architecture.

[Use this](http://www.genymotion.com/) it's x86 android emulator

Answer (score 1):

use geny motion. it is pretty fast.